# How to compare TIME() Type in Mysql + node

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, time

I got params from react to node
wanna compare Time() type and send it to react again.

However I got this err.

[image]

i suspect mysql query is wrong but i can't catch what i miss
this is my code

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code and errors as images, but as text instead.

Comment: SYNTAX ERROR: `=<`  Correct: `<=` (less than/equal), `>=` (greater than/equal), `<>` (not equal).  Look here for the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not about the `TIME()` function.

The less-than operator is `<=`, not `=<`.

Comment: AKX: you complained about text vs. image (I agree) ... then you substituted an ILLEGIBLE image!

Comment: @paulsm4 I only inlined OP's images, so you don't need to click through to see them.